# Connecting Mongodb sink connector and kafka

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying connect the mongodb kafka by using sink connector because i would like write the data from kafka to mongodb.I added mongodb connector jar file in libs folder and I have edited connect-standalone-demo.properties file like below,

```
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
# contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
# this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
# The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
# (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
# the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

# These are defaults. This file just demonstrates how to override some settings.
bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092

# The converters specify the format of data in Kafka and how to translate it into Connect data. Every Connect user will
# need to configure these based on the format they want their data in when loaded from or stored into Kafka
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
#value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
#key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
# Converter-specific settings can be passed in by prefixing the Converter's setting with the converter we want to apply
# it to
key.converter.schemas.enable=true
value.converter.schemas.enable=true

offset.storage.file.filename=/tmp/connect.offsets
# Flush much faster than normal, which is useful for testing/debugging
offset.flush.interval.ms=10000

# Set to a list of filesystem paths separated by commas (,) to enable class loading isolation for plugins
# (connectors, converters, transformations). The list should consist of top level directories that include 
# any combination of: 
# a) directories immediately containing jars with plugins and their dependencies
# b) uber-jars with plugins and their dependencies
# c) directories immediately containing the package directory structure of classes of plugins and their dependencies
# Note: symlinks will be followed to discover dependencies or plugins.
# Examples: 
# plugin.path=/usr/local/share/java,/usr/local/share/kafka/plugins,/opt/connectors,
# plugin.path=/home/adminacl/Kafka/kafka_2.13-3.1.0/libs
```

I have created file [file-sink-standalone.properties]which has configuration of db details.

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d ' {
      "connector.class":"com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSinkConnector",
      "tasks.max":"1",
      "topics":"departments",
      "connection.uri":"mongodb://localhost:27017",
      "database":"hrmdb",
      "collection":"departments",
      "key.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
      "key.converter.schemas.enable":false,
      "value.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
      "value.converter.schemas.enable":false
    
}
```

I am running the connector by using below cli,

```
bin/connect-standalone.sh config/connect-standalone-demo.properties config/file-sink-standalone.properties
```

I am getting following error,

```
ERROR Failed to create job for config/file-sink-standalone.properties (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone:107)
[2022-07-27 17:04:20,424] ERROR Stopping after connector error (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone:117)
```

Comment: Please show the full stacktrace. Looks like you've added a second commented `plugin.path` line. But also, you shouldn't add mongodb jars directly into the Kafka libs classpath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to uncomment **plugin.path** property in your connect-standalone-demo.properties [Worker]

In my environment all I have is this plugin.path=/usr/share/java for the most of the Sink Connectors and it works perfectly based on **connector.class** value from the Connector properties.

Have a read at https://docs.confluent.io/home/connect/self-managed/userguide.html#installing-kconnect-plugins

connector.class = com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSinkConnector

```
public class MongoSinkConnector extends SinkConnector {
    private Map<String, String> settings;

    @Override
    public String version() {
        return VersionUtil.getVersion();
    }

    @Override
    public void start(final Map<String, String> map) {
        settings = map;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<? extends Task> taskClass() {
        return MongoSinkTask.class;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Map<String, String>> taskConfigs(final int maxTasks) {
        return singletonList(settings);
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
    }

    @Override
    public ConfigDef config() {
        return MongoSinkConfig.CONFIG;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi. I have change jar file into java folder and plugin.path as per what you have mentioned. Still I am getting same error. I dont user docker. I am trying directly in my local. Connector.class what should I give?

Comment: I have updated my response. Connector.class is your implementation of your Connector that extends SinkConnector. I am talking from a JAVA implementation perspective. But all these can be done easily just through minimal configuration  via Confluent Center.

Comment: Why are you showing Java code? Existing Mongo Sink connector is open source and can be installed with Confluent Hub.

Comment: @OneCricketeer I have tried  that's also working fine. I would like implement same by using curl command for update the records (Put request). If you the configuration details could you share here?

Comment: @SherlinSusanna Not sure what you mean. MongoDB (nor Kafka) accept HTTP PUT requests. You'd need to write your own API for this. Please create a new post if you are having issues with this.

Comment: yeah. It will accept only post requests only which will update based on curl configurations. It's updating like it will insert new record with updated datetimestamp. But old record not getting updated. If i want to work as per my wish should I build my own custom connector?